# Timestamp guarda 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos en phpMyAdmin, con una columna "date_register" con:
Tipo: timestamp Null: No Predeterminado: current_timestamp()

Esta en automatico al guardar desde un form, mi problema es que no guarda la data time, pone todo en 0´s

¿Alguien sabe porque?

Busque videos en YT pero por más que los sigo sale el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien la pregunta, lo que entiendo es que queires que te guarde la fecha actual cuando se registre algun usuario ya intentante con un alter table?

ALTER TABLE tu_tabla
ALTER date_register SET DEFAULT NOW();
?